# Elasticsearch date histogram returning only maximum of 13 buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run the following query, and expecting 24 buckets to be present but 13 buckets are returned by elasticsearch.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": start_time,
              "lte": start_time + 86400
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "some_field": "some_value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "hourly_data": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "60m",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_some_agg_name": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "some_other_field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

I'm not able figure out how to set the bucket size of data_histogram.

Comment: you set the min_doc_count property to 0. Do you have the same results if you remove that setting and show also empty buckets?

Comment: Oh, that was my last trial to see if setting `min_doc_count: 0` will make any difference. Nope, its doesn't affect the result. I even tried retrieving information for last 2-3 days, its returning only the first 13 hours, remaining is truncated.